# Where was Wolverine running to, after he escaped?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Wolverine is shown to be escaping into a Narnia-like snowy place from the door of the lab.

**So, where was he escaping? Is there any hidden significance/meaning of the snow setting outside the laboratory.**

Comment: "Narnia-like snowy place" is a good way to describe Canada.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wolverine wasn't running *to* anywhere in particular. He was running *away from* the lab.

It's snowy because it's Canada, in winter.

(As revealed in [previous movies](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Alkali_Lake/Appearances), Stryker's lab is at [Alkali Lake, in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkali_Lake,_British_Columbia))

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the answer. I had a slight feeling that I was over-thinking that.  So, I indeed over-thought that scene :)